# Analogue of stateless and stateful beans in Spring

Tags: spring, ejb-3.1

Spring beans have 2 types of scopes (if you do not take into account scopes for web): `singleton`, which is default and `prototype`. Roughly they implement singleton and prototype design patterns within context.

So if the bean has prototype scope it can hold a unique state like the stateful bean in EJB. When the scope of the bean is singleton the container will create only one instance of it. So we can say that singleton beans in EJB 3.1 is the analogue of singleton beans in spring.

But how I can get the features of stateless beans in Spring (I'm referring to pooling of stateless beans in EJB containers and about that each thread has a unique instance of the stateless bean)?

Comment: Note that it's not really true that a thread has a unique instance. If a single thread does multiple calls after each other to the same bean, every call may end up in another instance. Rather, it's the other way around. Only one thread at a time can be active in a stateless session bean, and the framework automatically routes different requests to different instances.

Comment: Thanks, I mean just that you are talking about

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Either you can make the bean thread-safe, and a singleton bean is OK (that's the majority of the cases).

Or you can't, and you'll have to use a prototype. The difference I see between Spring prototype beans and stateless EJB session beans is that stateless session beans are pooled. But in these ages, pooling them or creating a new instance each time won't make much difference. Creating a new instance each time might even help the GC.

Comment: Pools also help with automatic resource throttling by setting the pool to an appropriate size. Furthermore, the bean instance *might* be cheap, but its associate resources might not be. Also, by using a proxy + pool pattern, injecting many 'beans' becomes very cheap and is no problem even if they end up not being used. Since the proxy in case of stateless beans is just akin to a URL that point to the pool.